# about finite discrete space

Tags: general-topology

question : is all finite discrete spaces are $T_2$- space, $T_1$ -space  and also $T_0$ -space. 
   i have taken very simple example: X = {a, b, c} and
topology $T = \{ ∅, X, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\} \}$. now it is clearly every  set containing in T is open as well as closed.
    first we verify for $T_0$:  clearly definition of $T_0$ is satisfied as there exists set containing one of two distinct points but not other.
    now we verify for $T_1$: clearly every singlton sets are closed hence $T_1$ 
    now we verify for $T_2$: also there exist set $U$ and $V$ such that $a \in U$ and $b \in V$ and $U \cap V = ∅$ 
    please tell me,  is am i right :-)

Comment: You have only shown that there exists a finite discrete space which is $T_2$, $T_1$ and $T_0$. However, the question asks you to find out if every finite discrete space has this property. (For this a little hint: the discrete topology is induced by a metric)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution gives only an example. But in discrete space every set is open (clopen, in fact; but you know this), hence it is at least $T_4$. Moreover, if you can show $T_2$, there is no need to verify $T_1$ and $T_0$.

And finiteness is meaningless..

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Corrected. Fineteness was misleading.

Comment: Sir,  you means every finite diacrete space is not T0 and T1 ?

Comment: @Akash No: every discrete space,ot only finite one, is $T_0$, $T_1$ and so on.